# best property to manipulate when tweening dom objects with a js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, tween

i'm searching for the best and performant way to animate some elements (with jquery or mootools).
for example, if i have to move an element, it's better to:

- absolutely positioning it and use top
  or left
- absolutely positioning it a use
  margin-top or margin-left
- fixed positioning it and use top or
  left
- create a big container and use the
  background-position

Comment: It all depends on what kind of animation you want to get. Animations in jQuery are for me the most interesting, sometimes the animation acts different whereas an element is positioned fixed/absolute or relative, width % / 'px' and so on. Never enough surprises and possibilities. Expetially using the jQuery UserInterface (UI) Now, for I don't understand your question... may you explain a bit?! WHAT KIND OF ANIMATION???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute position + margin manipulation can do a nice trick if you do not specify `left`/`top` values.

What trick?

The element with absolute position but no `left`/`top` will be rendered in the same position in which a static element would occur, while `margin-left`/`margin-top` will *add* to that position.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6PaE/1/

Overall, I appreciate you don't mention static position as an option — animating such element would cause unnecessary layout reflow, which is the main drawback of DOM/timeout animations.

Among the options you do consider, I think the most performant is the background option. But it has limited application, since you can move only graphic content. So I'd go for option #1.

Comment: I agree. and yes, it depends on what you are tweening. background image is probably going to be best insofar as performance as it does not really reposition elements so moving some images (or the appearance thereof, thats fine). else, `marginTop`/`Left` works great if your element is `absolute` as stated above. fixed is not x-browser, and modding top/left wont deal well with browser resizes.

Comment: thanks a lot. so, if it's possible, i'm going to tween the bg property everytime i can.